# QGIS Processing input list of numbers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

In QGIS you can input a set of raster or vectors using "##parameter_name=multiple raster" or "##parameter_name=multiple vector". Is it possible to do this with other acceptable parameter types, such as number? If not, is there another way to input a set of numbers (the exact number of which may change from run to run)?

The documentation showing you can use multiple raster and multiple vector (along with other types of input parameters) can be found here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most algorithms which do this accept a comma separated string, and split the string up into the numeric parts